# Dropdown Hide and Show HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Good Day! I already made my code show the appropriate dropdown as per the selected value on the first dropdown I have my code like this:

First Dropdown:

```
<select size="1" id="parent" class=" validate['required']" title="" type="select" name="style" >
    <option value="">-Choose-</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
```

When I chose any of this secondd dropdown will show for example when i choose "A" this next dropdown will show

```
<div id="A"  class="style-sub-1"  style="display: none;" name="stylesub1" >
        <label>A</label>
        <select id="childA">
            <option value="">-Choose-</option>
            <option value="Aa">Aa </option>
            <option value="Ab">Ab </option>
            <option value="Ac">Ac</option>
         </select>
 </div>
```

And then lastly when I choose again for example Aa, the third dropdown will be shown. This is the third dropdown

```
<div id="Aa"  class="style-sub-2"  style="display: none;" name="stylesub2" >
   <label>Aa:</label>
  <select >
    <option value="">-Choose-</option>
    <option value="Aaa">Aaa</option>
    <option value="Abb">Abb </option>
    <option value="Acc">Acc</option>
 </select>
```

Now, my problem is for example after I selected all these then decided to select another value from the first dropdown, for example B, the third dropdown which is Aaa is still shown. I need to hide this when I selected a new value to avoid confusion. How can I do that? This is my Javascript code:

```
<script>
    $("#parent").change ( function  () {
    var targID  = $(this).find(":selected").val()
    $("div.style-sub-1").hide ();
    $('#' + targID).show ();
    } )
    $("#childA").change ( function () {
    var targID  = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    $("div.style-sub-2").hide ();
    $('#' + targID).show ();
    } )
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

u can apply onchange function oh ur dropdowns as if first dropdown changes show second dropdown and same goes for second dropdown as if some one selects a value onlu then third dropdown will show

Comment: <select size="1" id="parent" class=" validate['required']" title="" type="select" name="style" onchange='showvalue(value)'>
    <option value="">-Choose-</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>

Comment: function showvalue(value) {if(value != ''){$('#a').show()}} and same goes for ur second and third dropdown u will apply onchange event to dropdown to show next dropdown only if something is selected as the value arguments accepts the value tht is selcted in the dropdown

Comment: Thanks but I tried this but when I chose A the second dropdown did not show